# Most Powerful test for indicating exponential or Weibull distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, exponential-distribution, weibull-distribution, neyman-pearson-lemma

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid distribution function of $F(x)$. I want to test whether $F$ is exponential or Weibull. This means that either $F(x)=1-exp(-x), x>0$ (exponential) $F(x)=1-exp(-x^{\theta}), x>0, \theta>0$ (Weibull). For this, I need to find the Most Powerful test for testing hypothesis $H:\theta=1$ vs $K:\theta=\theta_1>1$.

A further point I want to conclude is that this test is not UMP.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What distinction are you making between "most powerful" & "uniformly most powerful"? I could make sense of asking whether the most powerful test for the point alternative $\theta=2$ (say) is also the uniformly most powerful test for the composite alternative $\theta > 1$; or of asking whether the uniformly most powerful test for the composite alternative $\theta>1$, if there is one, is also the uniformly most powerful test for the composite alternative $\theta \neq 1$.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I have put the alternative hypothesis as $K: \theta=\theta_1>1$. Can you help on getting the MP test?

Comment: Sorry, I misread that as $K: \theta >1$. So you've to find the most powerful test of a point null vs a point alternative, which by the Neyman-Pearson lemma is the likelihood-ratio test - what part of the exercise are you stuck on?